# Grant execute on xp_logevent to sa using sa user to do it

Tags: sql-server, c#, sql-clr, signature

Running a SQL Server 2012 CLR stored procedure with this code:

```
const string executeLog = "EXEC master..xp_logevent @errorNumber, @message, informational";
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(executeLog, connection))
{
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@errorNumber", 60001);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@message", url);

    cmd.ExecuteScalar();
}
```

I get this error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The EXECUTE permission was denied
>   on the object 'xp_logevent', database 'mssqlsystemresource', schema
>   'sys'.

I've tried to do this as `sa` user:

```
grant execute on xp_logevent to sa
```

But I get another error:

> You can not find user 'sa' that does not exist or the user does not
>   have permission.

How can I grant execute permissions to sa user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I grant execute permissions to sa user?

You don't need to grant execute anything to `sa` as `sa` is in the `sysadmin` server role and can pretty much do anything. Hence, if you are getting an error executing `xp_logevent`, then you aren't logging in as `sa`. Is the connection string using `context connection = true;` or a regular / external connection? If using `context connection = true;` then the permissions are based on whoever is executing the SQLCLR stored procedure. If using a regular connection, the permissions are based on the logon account for the SQL Server NT Service (**MSSQLSERVER** / **SQLEXPRESS** if it is a default instance) by default, else it can be the permissions of whoever is executing the SQLCLR stored procedure if code has been added to do impersonation.

So, how is the `SqlConnection` being made? The answer to that question will help determine the appropriate fix. If this SQLCLR stored procedure is to be called by anyone (meaning, Users who are not necessarily in the `db_owner` database role or the `sysadmin` server role), then you can do the following to grant this permission to the smallest scope possible.

In the database that contains the SQLCLR stored procedure:

1. Create an Asymmetric Key (see [CREATE ASYMMETRIC KEY](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174430.aspx))
2. Create a User from that Asymmetric Key (see [CREATE USER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173463.aspx))
3. Add this new User to the `db_owner` Database Role
4. Create a T-SQL Stored Procedure (maybe call it `dbo.LogEvent`) that accepts the two parameters you are passing in (`@errorNumber` and `@message`) and simply executes `EXEC xp_logevent @errorNumber, @message, informational;`
5. Grant `EXECUTE` on this new Stored Procedure to any Users and/or Database Roles that will be calling the SQLCLR Stored Procedure
6. Sign this new Stored Procedure with the same Asymmetric Key used to create the new User (see [ADD SIGNATURE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181700.aspx))
7. Update your SQLCLR code to execute this new T-SQL Stored Procedure (i.e. `dbo.LogEvent`) instead of `xp_logevent`

   1. You can then change your `using` statement to have `new SqlCommand("dbo.LogEvent", connection)`
   2. then change `cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;` to be `cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;`
   3. remove the `const string executeLog` line

**Other notes:**

- Please do not use `AddWithValue` as there are issues with it. Instead, just create the `SqlParameter` with an explicitly set datatype and then add it to the `SqlCommand.SqlParameters` collection.
- No need to call `ExecuteScalar` if you are not capturing something from a result set. Instead, call `ExecuteNonQuery`

Answer (score 0):

You need to have below permissions as per MSDN

Requires membership in the db_owner fixed database role in the master database, or membership in the sysadmin fixed server role.